# How to show value of variable from a service.ts on my html - IONIC 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My requirement is quite simple - I have a service called `listproduct.service.ts`. This service has a variable called `checkfromservice = "check from service"`

Now I want this to be printed on `listproduct.html`. I have called it like this `{{checkfromservice}}`  but it's not printing.

In `listproduct.ts` I have imported the service:

`import { ListproductService } from './listproduct.service';`

and even included in providers `providers : [ ListproductService,DeleteProductService ],`

What else do I need to do to get it printed on HTML?

I am copying code for your reference if needed:

`listproduct.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ListproductService{
    private _url:string = "http://funiks.com/qbook/api/productmasterjson.php";
    constructor(private _http : Http){}

    checkfromservice="chk from service";

    listProduct(){

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post(this._url,{headers:headers}).map((response:Response) => response.json());
      // return this._http.post(this._url,{headers:headers})
       //.subscribe(data => {this.list = data; console.log(data[0].NAME);});

    }
}
```

`listproduct.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListproductService } from './listproduct.service';
import { DeleteProductService } from './deleteProduct.service';
import { ProductservicemasterPage } from '../productservicemaster/productservicemaster';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Generated class for the ListproductPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-listproduct',
  templateUrl: 'listproduct.html',
  providers : [ ListproductService,DeleteProductService ],
})
export class ListproductPage implements OnInit{
  public list = [];
  loading;
  constructor(private _listProduct : ListproductService,private _deleteProduct : DeleteProductService,
              public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

                this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                  content: 'Please wait...'
                });

              }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading.present();
     this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
       this.list = data;
      console.log(data[0].NAME);
      this.loading.dismiss();
      });
  }

  deleteProduct(list){
     this._deleteProduct.deleteProduct(list.ID).subscribe();
  }

  editProduct(list){
     this.navCtrl.push(ProductservicemasterPage,{"id":list.ID,"productService":list.PRODUCTSERVICE,"name":list.NAME,"unit":list.UNIT,"category":list.CATEGORY,"hsn":list.HSN,"postinghead":list.POSTINGHEAD,"rate":list.RATE,"type":list.TYPE,"sac":list.SACCODE,"tax":list.TAX_CONNECTED,"flag":"U"});
  }
}
```

`listproduct.html`

```
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>listproduct {{checkfromservice}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Try this `{{ _listProduct.checkfromservice }}` you have to use service `object` for access service's variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you explain yourself, the `checkfromservice` property is living inside the `ListproductService` class. So when using it in the component template, you need to refer to it the following way:

```
{{ _listProduct.checkfromservice }}
```

The reason for this is that the template code's scope, the the scope of the component it belongs to. So if you would have the `checkfromservice` declared directly in the component, you could have referred to directly in the template the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned answers you can access the variable in service from component using `servicename.variableNameInService`

Please check the sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yfbtxb which I created to check this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the "MVC" concept, you should not call your service directly in the HTML template.

The cleaner way to get the variable from a service is to create a public function in the controller that return `_listProduct.checkfromservice`.